# FFMPEG Video Trimming not correct on Android

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg

I've created a React Native app using this library `react-native-video-processing`, it works base on `ffmpeg`. The ffmpeg command I used for trimming video below:

`ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.400 -to 00:00:47 -preset ultrafast -c:v copy -c:a copy cut.mp4`

On the Android device, the result always have the duration 46s, that mean it always cut 1s instead of 400ms as the params above. Someone can help me in this case?

Comment: More example, if I use `-ss 00:00:01.400` it always cut 2s, seem it can not cut by milliseconds, just the second only.

Comment: Remove `-c:v copy` if you don't want to be limited to cutting on keyframes.